# Extrayendo caracteres alfanuméricos de cadenas en R

Tags: r, regex, string, funciones

Tengo una base de datos parecida a esto:

```
library(stringr) #Para la función str_extract

ejemplo <- data.frame(columna= c("{ em , 680/3 }", "no 659-11", "no funciona la 2507", 
    "a-4-2 no funciona", "p-8 con presencia de arena", " no 2-5c12s si sirve",
    "mecanica no 1ty -22s brinca"))
```

Me interesa extraer la parte de cada cadena que sea:

- Número
- Letra más número
- Número más letra

y, en general, las cadenas que se refieran a "identificadores".

Utilizando una sencilla expresión regular, puedo extraer

```
ejemplo$col2 <- ifelse(grepl("[0-9]+", ejemplo$columna), str_extract(ejemplo$columna, "[0-9]+"), NA)
ejemplo

                     columna col2
1              { em , 680/3 }  680
2                   no 659-11  659
3         no funciona la 2507 2507
4           a-4-2 no funciona    4
5  p-8 con presencia de arena    8
6         no 2-5c12s si sirve    2
7 mecanica no 1ty -22s brinca    1
```

que sólo tiene un buen resultado para la tercera cadena. Honestamente me siento perdido y no sé si exista una manera de hacer todo lo que quiero de una sola vez o tendré que construir diversas expresiones regulares para lograrlo. Agradezco mucho cualquier orientación al respecto.

El output deseado sería:

```
  deseado
1   680/3
2  659-11
3    2507
4   a-4-2
5     p-8
6 2-5c12s
7 1ty-22s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues se me ocurre la siguiente expresión, que es bastante compleja pero no veo cómo simplificarla:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z\/-]*[0-9]+)+[0-9a-zA-Z\/-]*
```

Se leería más o menos así:

- Comienza por cero o más repeticiones de letra, o signo `-` o signo `/`
- Sigue por al menos un dígito
- Todo lo anterior aparece al menos una vez, pero puede aparecer más veces
- Y después de nuevo puede venir cualquier cantidad de letras o números

En el fondo se trata de forzar a que aparezca al menos un dígito entre las letras, pues si hubiéramos intentado una expresión más sencilla como `[0-9a-zA-Z\/-]+` entonces habría encajado cualquier palabra del texto aunque no tuviera dígitos.

Demo de funcionamiento [en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/97NTJD/1)

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Abulafia hizo un gran trabajo encontrando una expresión monolítica que resuelve todos los casos que has presentado. Otra forma, es plantear múltiples patrones más exactos con cada `id`, dejando los más complejos y específicos al principio y los más genéricos al final:

```
patrones <- c('[0-9]-[0-9][a-z][0-9]+[a-z]',     # 2-5c12s
              '[0-9][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9][a-z]', # 1ty-22s
              '[a-z]-[0-9]+-[0-9]+',             # a-4-2
              '[0-9]+-[0-9][0-9]',               # 659-11
              '[0-9]+/[0-9]+',                   # 680/3
              '[a-z]-[0-9]+',                    # p-8
              '[0-9]+'                           # 2507
              )
str_extract(ejemplo$columna, paste(patrones, collapse = '|'))
[1] "680/3"   "659-11"  "2507"    "a-4-2"   "p-8"     "2-5c12s" "1ty-22s"
```

Construimos un vector con los patrones y los pegamos en una única cadena con un `|` (`or`). Esto es mucho menos performante que la solución de abulafia, pero en algunos casos puede hacer más clara la lógica.

Comment: En efecto, aunque como dices, la lógica es más clara, sobre todo para alguien como yo que es aprendiz. Gracias, Patricio :)